# How to use separated load balancers for frontend and backend in ECS?

Tags: load-balancing, terraform, amazon-ecs

I have the following terraform configuration for a load balancer running in ECS AWS for my django app container deployed in ECS:

```
resource "aws_lb" "api" {
  name               = "${local.prefix}-api"
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets = [
    aws_subnet.public_a.id,
    aws_subnet.public_b.id
  ]

  security_groups = [aws_security_group.lb_api.id]

  tags = local.common_tags
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "api" {
  name        = "${local.prefix}-api"
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id
  target_type = "ip"
  port        = 8000

  health_check {
    path = "/admin/login/"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "api" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.api.arn
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      port        = "443"
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "api_https" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.api.arn
  port              = 443
  protocol          = "HTTPS"

  certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert.certificate_arn

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.api.arn
  }
}


resource "aws_security_group" "lb_api" {
  description = "Allow access to Application Load Balancer"
  name        = "${local.prefix}-lb-api"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 8000
    to_port     = 8000
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = local.common_tags
}
```

I have an almost identical file for the react frontend container. The only differences are the replacement of the word "api" for "frontend", the target group port (which is 80 in the case of frontend load balancer), and the health check path (just "/" for frontend)

When I deploy only the API, I can normally access the application on browser. However, when I add the frontend load balancer, I  cannot access the frontend in the browser (error "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable"). The django application kept working but after a while, it also went down.

I look at the ECS UI and I note that the cluster, the task and the containers are running without problems. But I keep getting errors in health checks. I think this error is probably related to the ports mapping. But the mappings are consistent with the [container-definitions](https://gist.github.com/lucascr91/f16c0a198dd369b431c51035ea697c32) file.

What is the possible reason for this?